# Data Manipulation from Log File

Tags: c#

I have a long Log.txt file that contains a lot of data that looks like this:

```
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
001 001 1.56 1.52 1.51 1.56
001 002 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.67
001 003 0.5 0.4949 0.49 0.5
001 004 0.96 0.9601 0.96 0.9601
001 005 0.5291 0.5001 0.5 0.54
002 000 2.4537 2.4422 2.43 2.4537
002 003 0.5 0.51 0.4945 0.515
002 005 0.5 0.4801 0.4801 0.5
003 000 2.43 2.3399 2.3399 2.43
003 003 0.5101 0.5087 0.5005 0.5289
003 004 1 0.998 0.98 1
003 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
```

What is the easiest and the most professional way to separate this data in to lists by the 2nd column.
Ex:
list 1

```
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
002 000 2.4537 2.4422 2.43 2.4537
003 000 2.43 2.3399 2.3399 2.43
```

and list 2

```
001 001 1.56 1.52 1.51 1.56
```

and list 3

```
001 002 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.67
```

and so on..

I'm very inexperienced so what I would probably do is:

- trim every line to the second space (" ")
- create "**for i**" statement and
- and create new lists  `if (line2.Contains(i.ToString("D3")))` Add...

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

FYI, as a finished product I want to go through each line, remove all duplicates, and add all these numbers to 5 arrays (5 different arrays 001 to 005) and count duplicates.

Comment: actual code will explain your idea better then words

Comment: *remove all duplicates* followed by *count duplicates* makes absolutely no sense. How can you *count duplicates* if you *remove all duplicates* first? Also, this isn't a code writing service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself. Once you have, you can explain the problem you've encountered, include the relevant portions of your code, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help you solve that problem.

Comment: I added example of lists. Yea, I want to remove duplicates from each line 1st. but when i combine all lines (by 2nd column) there will be more duplicates that I want to count. Sorry if I'm being unclear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read each line with [`System.IO.File.ReadLines()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readlines?view=netframework-4.7.2), split by whitespace, and store the lines in a key-value `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`, where the key is second column.

**Demo:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverFlow {

    public static class Program {

        # Store everything here
        private static Dictionary<string, List<string>> data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

        public static void Main(string[] args) {

            // Read all lines into array
            string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"Log.txt");
            foreach (string line in lines) {

                // Split line by whitespace
                string[] columns = line.Split(' ');

                // Key is second column
                string key = columns[1];

                // Add line to dictionary, also making sure list is initialised
                if (!data.ContainsKey(key)) {
                    data.Add(key, new List<string>());
                }
                data[key].Add(line);
            }

            // Print out results
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> entry in data) {
                Console.WriteLine(entry.Key);

                foreach (string line in entry.Value) {
                    Console.WriteLine(line);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
000
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
002 000 2.4537 2.4422 2.43 2.4537
003 000 2.43 2.3399 2.3399 2.43

001
001 001 1.56 1.52 1.51 1.56

002
001 002 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.67

003
001 003 0.5 0.4949 0.49 0.5
002 003 0.5 0.51 0.4945 0.515
003 003 0.5101 0.5087 0.5005 0.5289

004
001 004 0.96 0.9601 0.96 0.9601
003 004 1 0.998 0.98 1

005
001 005 0.5291 0.5001 0.5 0.54
002 005 0.5 0.4801 0.4801 0.5
003 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
```

Comment: thank you so much, i found that this solution works best for me. I'm still using your original one.

Answer (score 2):

I find that it's generally simplest to create a record type to import the lines into.  I have no idea what your actual columns are, so mess with this until you get something more meaningful to you:

```
public class LogEntry
{
    public string GroupIndex;
    public string GroupKey;
    public float Value1;
    public float Value2;
    public float Value3;
    public float Value4;
}
```

Now load your log file as an `IEnumerable<LogEntry>` and you can use LINQ to do the work for you:

```
public static IEnumerable<LogEntry> OpenLog(string filename)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        string line = null;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] parts = line.Split(' ');
            if (parts.Length != 6)
                continue;
            float f1, f2, f3, f4;
            if (!float.TryParse(parts[2], out f1) || !float.TryParse(parts[3], out f2) || !float.TryParse(parts[4], out f3) || !float.TryParse(parts[5], out f4)
                continue;
            yield return new LogEntry
            {
                GroupIndex = parts[0],
                GroupKey = parts[1],
                Value1 = f1,
                Value2 = f2,
                Value3 = f3,
                Value4 = f4,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now that we have access to the file data as concrete records that LINQ can chew over, grouping will take care of the bulk of your question.  First, let's group by the second column of your data (called `GroupKey` in the record above):

```
var groupedEntries =
(
    from entry in OpenLog(logfilename)
    // first group by the group key - second column in data
    group entry by entry.GroupKey into grp
    select new
    {
        Group = grp.Key,
        Data = grp.ToArray(),
    }
).ToArray();
```

You can now take the resulting arrays and process them separately to get your duplicates.  For the sake of argument I'll assume that you're looking for duplicate values across all 4 value fields.  The same applies for other comparisons...

```
var deduplicated = 
(
    from grp in groupedEntries
    let dedup = 
    (
        from ent in grp
        group ent.GroupIndex by new { ent.Value1, ent.Value2, ent.Value3, ent.Value4 } into ddgrp
        let first = grp.First()
        select new 
        {
            first.GroupIndex, first.GroupKey,
            first.Value1, first.Value2, first.Value3, first.Value4,
            Count = ddgrp.Count(),
        }
    ).ToArray()
    select new
    {
        grp.Key,
        Data = dedup,
    }
).ToArray();
```

Now you have an array of records like this (in JSON):

```
[
    {
        "Group": "000",
        "Data": [
            {
                "GroupIndex": "001",
                "GroupKey": "000",
                "Value1": 2.59,
                "Value2": 2.4595,
                "Value3": 2.4573,
                "Value4": 2.62,
                "Count": 1
            },
            {
                "GroupIndex": "001",
                "GroupKey": "001",
                "Value1": 2.4537,
                "Value2": 2.4422,
                "Value3": 2.43,
                "Value4": 2.4537,
                "Count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The `GroupIndex` field in the output is from the first row with the values.  Subsequent rows are removed but counted.

Of course I could have just made this a single LINQ query.  The second query could just include the grouping from the first one... but I think it's easier to read this way.

Comment: Very nice. Does `LogEntry` act as a struct here?

Comment: Yeah, but reference types (classes) are a tiny bit more efficient when you're doing LINQ... even though the anonymous types I'm using in the selects are going to be structs.  I just tend to avoid explicit structs by habit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `LINQ` to do this. It can also handle duplicates in the output. I put them into a `List<List<string>>` since we don't know how many lists to create.

This will probably work for `n` number of `Lists`, but I haven't really tested it that much.

```
// // Get all lines from File
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines("..\\..\\Test.txt");

// Gets only the values in the second column and groups by it. (Removing duplicates).
var groups = allLines.Distinct().GroupBy(line => line.Split(' ')[1]);

// This is your output. Put it in a List of Lists for unknown size
List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>();

// Basically, for each group select then lines from the
// file where the second column matches the group.
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    lists.Add(allLines.Select(lines => lines).Where(groupNum => groupNum.Split(' ')[1] == group.Key).ToList());
}

// Print out stuff
foreach(List<string> container in lists)
{
    Console.WriteLine("List: " + container.First().Split( ' ')[1]);
    foreach(string individualString in container)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(individualString);
    }
}
```

An input of:

```
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62 // Duplicate
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62 // Duplicate
001 001 1.56 1.52 1.51 1.56
001 002 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.67
001 003 0.5 0.4949 0.49 0.5
001 004 0.96 0.9601 0.96 0.9601
001 005 0.5291 0.5001 0.5 0.54
002 000 2.4537 2.4422 2.43 2.4537
002 003 0.5 0.51 0.4945 0.515
002 005 0.5 0.4801 0.4801 0.5
003 000 2.43 2.3399 2.3399 2.43
003 003 0.5101 0.5087 0.5005 0.5289
003 004 1 0.998 0.98 1
001 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
001 006 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
001 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49 // Duplicate
003 008 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
001 009 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
```

Produces:

```
List: 000
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
001 000 2.59 2.4595 2.4573 2.62
002 000 2.4537 2.4422 2.43 2.4537
003 000 2.43 2.3399 2.3399 2.43
List: 001
001 001 1.56 1.52 1.51 1.56
List: 002
001 002 0.67 0.66 0.66 0.67
List: 003
001 003 0.5 0.4949 0.49 0.5
002 003 0.5 0.51 0.4945 0.515
003 003 0.5101 0.5087 0.5005 0.5289
List: 004
001 004 0.96 0.9601 0.96 0.9601
003 004 1 0.998 0.98 1
List: 005
001 005 0.5291 0.5001 0.5 0.54
002 005 0.5 0.4801 0.4801 0.5
001 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
001 005 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
List: 006
001 006 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
List: 008
003 008 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
List: 009
001 009 0.49 0.4802 0.4362 0.49
```

If you want to remove the duplicates from the output just move the `.Distinct()` call from `var groups` and append it to `File.ReadAllLines()`.